# SonarCFamily only detects code-smells duplicate code blocks

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to use SonarScanner with SonarCFamily plugin on my C codebase on ubuntu. I see that the scanner is able to only detect "code smells - duplicate blocks of code" in my codebase and no other forms of bugs/vulnerabilities. I intentionally added a memory leak in the code and SonarQube couldn't detect it while open source SA tool Cppcheck was able to. Am I missing some setting in the sonar-project.properties file ? My sonar.properties file is as follows. Are there any settings needed in the server/SonarCFamily plugin for the tool to detect other forms of SA errors ?

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=c-sa-test
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=c-sa-test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
sonar.sources=src

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw_output
sonar.c.file.suffixes=.c,.h
sonar.cpp.file.suffixes=.cc,.cpp,.cxx,.c++,.hh,.hpp,.hxx,.h++,.ipp
```

Comment: Do you actually have rules in the profile that's applied? You can see which profiles are used on the project homepage, bottom-right.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Following are the profiles being applied as per the project homepage: Quality Profiles

    (C)c-default-2017
    (Python)py-default-2017
    (Web)web-default-2017
    (XML)xml-default-2017   For c-default-2017 following is the rules summary: Rules
 Active Inactive
Total 133 105
Bugs 37 21
Vulnerabilities 2 0
Code Smells 94 84
Deprecated Rules

Comment: and is your bw_output file non-empty?

Comment: And those files are non-empty?

Comment: The bw_output directory is non-empty with 2 files: build-wrapper-dump.json of 505 bytes and build-wrapper.log of 99430 bytes, I see quite a few rules that are inactive in the c-default-2017 profile. Could that be contributing to this behavior ?

Comment: Yes @Naikster, it could

Comment: Found the root cause. Was missing some elements of the project build process as input to the build wrapper. Once those were added, SonarQ provided a detailed report. Thanks for your help in debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause - Was missing providing some elements of the project build process as input to the build wrapper. Once those were added, SonarQ provided a detailed report.

Comment: Can you specificity which particular elements of the build were missing, and if you have any relevant information on it, why that was causing the problem? My team is experiencing the exact same issue when trying to analyze a project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem where SonarCFamily was only reporting code duplications.  It was due to an incorrect build process as input to the build wrapper.  In my case, I was using SonarScanner.MSBuild and on my build-wrapper line, I didn't have the Configuration and Platform specified, so my projects were not getting built or scanned.  The final working lines were:

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"your key" /d:sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=”bw_output”

build-wrapper-win-x86-64.exe --out-dir bw_output MSBuild.exe your_solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end